# Bar chart school exercise - Get bars to scroll smothly across screen - JS vanilla

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, css-animations

I have a school assignment where we want to visualize a "queue data" (which we don't have and therefore fake). You have to make the data appears on screen with bars of different heights etc.
There are extras for this assignment and one of them is making each new bar (ergo each new data value) not jump in but smoothly appear in a constant scroll.

I have put an animation in all .bars and made the animation scroll smoothly.
It works for the first bar and then it doesn't.

(We are working with for loops if it helps)

Here is the code:

```js
"use strict";

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

const model = [];

const barArray = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
const peopleInQueue = document.querySelector(".people_in_queue");

let timeoutSpeed = 1000;

function init() {
  console.log("init");
  loop();
}

// Controller
function loop() {
  arrUpdate();
  displayData();
  setTimeout(loop, timeoutSpeed);
}

// Model
function arrUpdate() {
  if (model.length < 40) {
    model.unshift(getNumberOfCustomers());
  } else {
    model.length = 39;
    model.unshift(getNumberOfCustomers());
  }
  console.log(model);
}

// View
function displayData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    barArray.textContent = model[i];
    barArray[i].style.height = `${model[i]}px`;

    peopleInQueue.textContent = "";
    // add display of number of people in the queue
    barArray[i].addEventListener("mouseover", (hoverPeopleNumber) => {
      peopleInQueue.textContent = `There are ${model[i]} persons in the queue`;
    });

    if (model[i] < 15) {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `yellowgreen`;
    } else if (model[i] < 25) {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `yellow`;
    } else if (model[i] < 35) {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `orange`;
    } else {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `red`;
    }
  }
}

function getNumberOfCustomers() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 32);
}
```

```css
#bars {
  display: flex;
  height: 5rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* animation: scroll 1s linear backwards; */
  margin-left: 1px;
}

 


/* scroll smoothly doesn't work  */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bar Chart</h1>
    <main>
      <div id="bars">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="people_in_queue"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me find out why it doesn't continue scrolling, I've been on this for hours and I may have a simple error but i really can't find it. I feel like maybe I didn't target the whole thing and just a single thing and that the animation don't continue through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

All the `.bar` divs exist from the beginning so they all do the animation once and then they all stop. Only the first one is visible so it looks like only the first one animates. Here is what it looks like with the animation repeated indefinitely (and with `translateX(50px)` changed to `translateX(11.5px)`).

```js
"use strict";

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

const model = [];

const barArray = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
const peopleInQueue = document.querySelector(".people_in_queue");

let timeoutSpeed = 1000;

function init() {
  console.log("init");
  loop();
}

// Controller
function loop() {
  arrUpdate();
  displayData();
  setTimeout(loop, timeoutSpeed);
}

// Model
function arrUpdate() {
  if (model.length < 40) {
    model.unshift(getNumberOfCustomers());
  } else {
    model.length = 39;
    model.unshift(getNumberOfCustomers());
  }
  console.log(model);
}

// View
function displayData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    barArray.textContent = model[i];
    barArray[i].style.height = `${model[i]}px`;

    peopleInQueue.textContent = "";
    // add display of number of people in the queue
    barArray[i].addEventListener("mouseover", (hoverPeopleNumber) => {
      peopleInQueue.textContent = `There are ${model[i]} persons in the queue`;
    });

    if (model[i] < 15) {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `yellowgreen`;
    } else if (model[i] < 25) {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `yellow`;
    } else if (model[i] < 35) {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `orange`;
    } else {
      barArray[i].style.backgroundColor = `red`;
    }
  }
}

function getNumberOfCustomers() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 32);
}
```

```css
#bars {
  display: flex;
  height: 5rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  animation: scroll 1s linear backwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(11.5px);
  }
}


/*!!!!!! scroll smoothly doesnt work  */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bar Chart</h1>
    <main>
      <div id="bars">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="people_in_queue"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```